# Recording a video with watermark using mediacodec without ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, encode, android-mediacodec

How can I draw an image watermark when I'm recording a video with mediacodec in Android without ffmpeg?

I found this sample code [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java) but was drawed just a red square.
I need to draw an image OR a text.